# ajax keyword search from the database in drupal

Tags: jquery, ajax, search, drupal-7, keyword

this is the code for ajax search i have :

```
function mymodule_menu() {
    $items = array();
    $items['ajaxsearch'] = array(
             'title' => 'Search Through ajax', //page title
            'description' => 'A form to mess around with.',
            'page callback' => 'drupal_get_form',
            'page arguments' => array('ajaxsearch_form'),
            'access arguments' => array(''),
            'access callback' => TRUE,
            'type' => MENU_CALLBACK
    );


    return $items;
}
function ajaxsearch_form($form, &$form_state) {
    $form = array();

    $form['search'] = array(
            '#title' => t('search the name'),
            '#type' => 'textfield',

    );


    $form['submit'] = array(
            '#type' => 'submit',
            '#value' => 'submit',
    );

    return $form;
}

function ajaxsearch_form_submit($form,&$form_state){

}


?>
```

please send me the code for ajax search data from the database in drupal when i am typing d in text box ..it will show the data related to k in database help me .

Comment: Check this http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/81810/ajax-autocomplete

Comment: not working ... another linkk you have ??